# What does a */* mean in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does a */* mean in a sentence, for example, "They read/reviewed the books they have." I can't find an answer to this question, but they only get an opinion which is what I do not need.

Comment: It means *and*, *or*, or *and/or*. Seriously. Depends on context.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Slashes.htm

Comment: @DanBron Do you have an example where `/` means *and*?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Top two results in a google search, [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)#Connecting_non-contrasting_items) give these examples respectively: *enrolling in the JD/MBA program at Harvard* and *the Hemingway/Faulkner generation*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: the example given in the question can be read that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be very clear, my understanding is that a / (slash) is just an easy way or symbol of saying "and or or" (an example I could've used there is and/or!)

In your example, the sentence is just meaning:

> They read and/or reviewed the books they have.

If you want to find a clearer definition, you could also call the "/" character a *virgule*. There are many other names, but these are the most popular.

Grammar Definition - (http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/slashterm.htm)

Comment: "They read/reviewed the books they have." may mean 1) "They read or reviewed the books they have." or 2) They read and reviewed the books they have."